# Why is there no neutral [Cr(OC)6] or anionic [Fe(NC)6] - isomers of cyanide and carbonyl complexes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, ligand-field-theory, carbonyl-complexes

I was just reading about linkage isomerism, that usually arise due to the fact that some ligands are [ambidentate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_isomerism) (i.e. $\ce{SCN}$ and $\ce{NCS}$).

I then think to myself, considering only the ligand structure, $\ce{CN-}$ and $\ce{CO}$ ligand also should also be ambidentate ligands (I'm not including bridging). However, I haven't found any reference to that. Here's now, my questions:

- Are $\ce{CN-}$ and $\ce{CO}$ really ambidentate? why or why not?
- How different are the complexes? (i.e. $\ce{Cr(OC)6}$ vs $\ce{Cr(CO)6}$)

Also, if anyone found a complex with $\ce{NC-}$ or $\ce{OC}$ ligand, please do put the reference to that.

Comment: And why not include bridging? That's the main situation you get O-coordinated carbonyls.

Comment: Mostly for personal preference. However, I felt like bridging force the ligand to use more than one electrons pair at the same time, instead of having 2 (or more) electrons pair that can be used in multiple ways.

Comment: Well, in the answer, there sure is bridging...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of cyanide we actually do have iron coordinated to the nitrogen ends of the cyanide ligands in [Prussian blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prussian_blue). In fact  iron atoms are coordinated to *both* ends of the cyanide ion ligands; the iron forms a simple cubic lattice with the cyanide ions laid out along the edges of the cube like an expanded perovskite structure:

[image]

[From Wikimedia Commons user Ben Mills](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Iron-coordination-in-simplified-Prussian-blue-from-xtal-xray-3D-bs-17.png#mw-jump-to-license)

[image]

[From Wikipedia user Smokefoot](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Idealized,_defect-free_Prussian_Blue.svg#mw-jump-to-license)

In general, the pi-acceptor ligand that cyanide ion is will bond first through the less electronegative carbon atom, where the $\pi^*$ orbitals that accept electrons from the metal have higher amplitudes (and thus potentially better overlap). But when that bond is already taken up, as in the Prussian blue structure or with nitrile ligands where the cyanide carbon is bonded to another carbon atom, then the nitrogen end of the cyanide can from a second bond.